# VBA EXCEL - open file and assign path to a new workbook path

Tags: excel, vba, file, path, namespaces

there.
i'm trying to pass a file path for defining a new workbook's path... All seems fine until I get a "Subscript out of range" at the line:

Set rngS = Workbooks(wkbS).Range("myRange1")

I've reduced the original file name length, as well as for its folder directory name, etc...
I've also switched type definitions between string, variant, etc...
I'd appreciate any suggestions.
txs a lot.

[image: Error]

```
Sub myMain()

dim wkbS as string
dim rngS as range

wkbS = open_file_src
Debug.Print "w_source_path is : " & wkbS

Set rngS = Workbooks(wkbS).Range("myRange1")      
debug.print "Range rngS : " & rngS.address
End Sub


Function open_file_src() As String
   
    strFile_src = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel files,*.x*", Title:="Select SOURCE file")
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFile_src
    Debug.Print "open_file_src PATH is : " & strFile_src
    
    open_file_src = strFile_src
        
End Function
```

Comment: There are some inconsistencies here: 1) wkbT is defined as a Workbook Collection object and you are trying to define it as Thisworkbook. 2) The line you mentioned tries to read a range from a closed workbook. You must first open it or use other techniques to do so. The subsequent line attempts to directly read a range from a Workbook object the way used to read one from a sheet. Some variables are not DIMmed.

Comment: Hi, AleXcel. I will clean up the code. txs.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the name of the target Workbook without it's path as it is open on Excel:

```
wkbS="ChoosedWorkbook.xls"
```

And then there are two ways to set rngS range:

```
Set rngS =  = Workbooks(wkbS).Names("myRange1").RefersToRange
```

or, passing the sheet name wich contains the target range:

```
Set rngS = Workbooks(wkbS).Sheets("theNameOfTheSheet").Range("myRange1")
```

The modified code to get the filename:

```
Function open_file_src() As String
   Dim strFile_src As String
    strFile_src = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel files,*.x*", Title:="Select SOURCE file")
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFile_src
    Debug.Print "open_file_src PATH is : " & strFile_src
    
    open_file_src = Right(strFile_src, Len(strFile_src) - InStrRev(strFile_src, "\"))
        
End Function
```